# Replacing chars in string

Tags: windows, cobol, microfocus

I have this code:

```
inspect w-string1 replacing all x'C48D' by 'c'
```

But I got this error by compiler

> Operand has wrong size

Is there any solution how to replace more chars by one char thru inspect command. Or I must do it by myself via perform loop?

Comment: `INSPECT ... REPLACING` only replaces with the same length. But you can use a simple `MOVE` when you one-time code an user defined function for the replacing.
... or use a different compiler which has something like `FUNCTION SUBSTITUTE` in already (GnuCOBOL does).

Answer (score 3):

When using the INSPECT statement, both strings must be the same length. The only way to replace multiple characters by a different number of characters is to write your own loop to do it.

Comment: Hard to imagine why this is not a standard function! The people who put the standards must be out of touch with this planet!